# how to send smtp mails with java over microsoft exchange cloud

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I need to send mails with java mail from a webserver over an exchange account. the exchange account is registered with a domain owned by our company, which has the exchange account as its MX entry. I did some research on how to accomblish this, as I was not able to find out any plain information about some kind of smtp outlook might be using. Ive no idea which server I need to connect to and how to authenticate to it. I do not have any experience with any microsoft technology. I found some guides for .NET frameworks like [Introducing the Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

But this seems to be very less helpfull!? I also found some Java frameworks like [exJello](http://www.exjello.org/) which looks pretty good, but I didnt manage to configure it properly so far as I dunno any property values.

I would not like tu purchase any big framework, I do not have to manage any exchange related features, the only requirement to this connection would be to send mails.

My question is, how can I connect to my exchange account and send mails with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of research and lots of misleading information I found the information about the properties I needed in some option in my exchange admin webinterface. So the connection to the smtp is nothing different from a normal stmp service

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you need to ask the network administrator for your company how to configure a mail client to use your company's mail server.  They should be able to tell you what host name to use, etc.

Comment: well the funny thing is, I am the admin for those system. Actuelly I am a Softwaredeveloper but so far I have to manage the mailserver myself. I bought the exchange license so that I dont have to set up a mail server myself. It had to be a fast, easy and safe solution to set the mx record and handle the mail traffic.

Comment: Then you know the name of the host that's running the Exchange server.  Configure the server to support SMTP, choose whether to require SSL or not, and then configure JavaMail to connect accordingly.  There's lots of examples of how to configure JavaMail in the JavaMail FAQ.

Comment: I do not know that, configuring JavaMail is not my problem. where, for example in outlook or the web administration panel can I retrive the information about the host? the exchange server is in a cloud at microsoft, outlook configuers some proxys and fancy things. Dont know how to cennect to it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I've never used Microsoft's cloud.  Try asking Microsoft for help.